# How to handle 3D touch gesture on Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Is there available `GestureRecognizer` on Xamarin UIKit for handling 3D touch - `Force touch` ?

I want to handle `Peek` and `Pop` gestures with the `Force` measuring.

Comment: This guide should tell you everything you need to know:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/3dtouch/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a 3D Touch Gesture recognizer in iOS, however you can create a custom one by subclassing `UIGestureRecognizer`.